# Making water spin a wheel

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

Let's say that I have a wheel with 8 symmetric arranged rectangular plates of area $A$ and the water, with density $\rho$,  in the river it moves with $v\: \mathrm{m/s}$.

How do I calculate the angular velocity of the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the wheel moves at the same speed as the water (ie: neglecting and 'slip' of the wheel past the water),

angular velocity is given by:

$$\omega = v / r$$

where $r$ is the 'radial' distance from the centre of the wheel to the top of the water.

In practice, there will be some water sliding past the wheel, depending upon the hydrodynamics of the plates and channel, so this is really an ideal first approximation.

Comment: But , the wheel moves with the same velocity?

Comment: The 'tip' if the wheel (plate) moves at the same velocity as the water... of course, this is not exactly true, but is a first approximation. In reality, the wheel will spin slower. How much slower depends upon the channel depth, plate dimensions, gaps at the edges, bearing friction for the wheel... etc. etc...